# Can a Null enter the Warp?

Tags: warhammer-40k

In Warhammer 40k, Nulls or (in more extreme cases) Pariahs are humans whose very presence cuts off access to the Warp. As such, it would seem that they could potentially beat Chaos on its own turf—*if* they could get there.

Are Nulls even capable of entering the Warp?

Comment: Do you mean "travel in warp" like in the ship? Then yes, of course. If you mean "enter the warp physically without protection of the Gellar Field", then... not so sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Sisters of Silence is a force made up largely of psychic nulls, their black ships travel through the warp on their missions to find and capture errant psychers. A more specific example from a Horus Heresy book I just finished reading is Iota, a Culexus Assassin and psychic null, who is present while the main characters are traveling through the warp.

Comment: Then I suppose the logical question is whether they could challenge the Chaos Gods?

Comment: @Adamant They could not challenge the Chaos Gods as whether the powers come from Chaos or not, physical effects from actions by creatures of Chaos don't just stop happening in their presence. A Greater Daemon swinging his Daemon Sword at a tank will still split it in twain.  Regardless of whether a Culexus Assassin was inside it or not. Gods being on another level, if one of them could manifest it would as a minimum probably take Emperor Titan-size form, and if it stood on a NULL, they'd still be squished.

Comment: The Culexus assassin in Nemesis (spoilers ahead) is killed by a warp creature merged with a "black pariah" (like a pariah but they can turn psychic powers back on their users instead of just negating them). The assassin uses a psychic weapon to try and kill this creature but it's reflected back and kills them instead, so I would imagine much stronger psychic forces like the Chaos Gods wouldn't be stopped either

Comment: Sisters of silence travel in a ships protected by Gellar fields, that create reality bubble around them. So they are not technically IN the warp.

Comment: @Philbo You assume that in the Warp demonic sword will have physical effects. I am not sure is there ANYTHING physical in the warp. Yes, demon can throw a rock at a Null while they both standing in the reality, but in the Warp there are no "rocks" to throw, only the concept of them... and nulls are  anti-concepts. It would be like throwing rock at a Black Hole.

Comment: @Yasskier - Then my worry would be that that in combination with the idea that a Null could cancel unlimited sorcery might lead to the conclusion that Nulls are all but all-powerful forces of destruction in the Warp - a conclusion that the Empire certainly never seems to have reached.

Comment: This comment is late, but in the *Ravenor* series, there is a null who's negating powers are at one point overwhelmed and permanently burned out by a particularly powerful psiker (note that this Pariah had on multiple occasions completely negated *multiple* alpha level psikers). This canonically establishes that there is a limit, albeit a very high limit, to how much warp energy a blank can nullify. I imagine that even the most powerful null would be overwhelmed by the amount of Warp energy in the Warp itself, and certainly by the power of a chaos god.

Answer (score 1):

Jurgen, Ciaphus (***HERO OF THE IMPERIUM!***) Cain's adjutant is a null and travels with him all the time on Warp-capable ships, so the answer is clearly yes.

Comment: Any null can travel in a ship protected by Gellar field, just like ordinary human, because this field creates bubble of reality around the vessel. So Jurgen (and few other named nulls - like Bequin) is not in the Warp.

Comment: @Yasskier - You could write an answer.

Comment: I think Jurgen is protected by repetitive dialog and repetitive dialog, rather than any Gellar field.

Answer (score 1):

To quote 1d4Chan - "[Things to do when you are in warp](https://1d4chan.org/wiki/Warp#Things_to_do_in_the_Warp)":

> If you're a Null... How the f@#k did you manage that? Oh well, you're pretty much invincible. Have fun, troll away.
>
> Keep in mind that anything you touch or even approach (depending on your power) would dissolve into nothing. This includes the things you're standing on, like floors, bridges and stairs. This may even include air - so while psykers and even regular humans can get away by believing there is air around and warp being twisted by their will to manifest that believes you're stuck with what you brought with you from the realspace.

The answer to this question is similar to the answer for "Can a man who never dreamed enter the dreamland?". Difficult, that is:

Lets first answer few basic questions:

1. Warp is "an adaptation of Carl Jung's concept of the Collective Unconscious, a conceptual Metaphysical dimension created by the common thoughts present in each sapient lifeform". In other words, nothing physical exists there, just like nothing physical exists in your dream. You can dream that you hit your head and wake up with a headache, but it is your body responding to what your mind told you (or other way around: you might go to sleep with a headache and dream about being hit in the head).
2. Demons don't have physical forms. To enter reality they need to be summoned, which creates a weak spot in reality and allows them to construct body from the "reality stuff" using their warp powers (via possession), or creating "warp bubble" around themselves, that allows them to exist in the realspace. They are really resilient to physical attacks that in fact only banish them back to the Immaterium.
3. Similarly as demons coming to our world, ships enter the warp by creating a powerful field that creates a bubble of reality around them. So we have a real ship (with its content, which can include Blanks) entering Immaterium.
4. <s>Alive</s> Soul possessing beings (which include certain inanimated object that posses Machine Spirit) can enter the warp directly, which is of course extremely dangerous (unless you are a Chaos Champion, that is). When they do, they stop existing physically and became their immaterial counterpart, just as in real space theirs soul don't exist "physically" but are somehow part of your physical body (sort of...)
5. Blanks don't have the immaterial representation of them. If somehow they would get into the Warp, probably one of the three things could happen:

a) Blank stops existing: without the immaterial counterpart there is no "immaterial" representation of him/her.

b) Warp spits him back immediately

c) He/she enter a warp has a small bubble of reality around him, with its size depending on the blank's power. Analogical to demon in the real world, he would be almost invulnerable, but not omnipotent - he couldn't be damaged by pure magic but he still could be "banished" back to the realsapce.

Comment: I think the answer is C


otherwise the blanks could not travel on warp ships around the imperium

Comment: @TheRWS96 As i've mentioned before, ships travel inside a bubble of reality created by Gellar field. This means that anyone in the ship is not technically in the warp, in similar way that when you are in the submarine you are not in the water.

Comment: yesterday, oh sorry i think i interpreted C wrong then, could you change the "He/she enter a warp but besides a small bubble of reality" to "He/she enter a warp but has a small bubble of reality" or "He/she enter a warp but forms a small bubble of reality" that would be a bit clearer i think.